# Unable to re-sync data from remote XML using phonegap and html5sql.js for android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, web-sql

Here is my whole script:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); //add event for phonegap

    function resync(){

    var serviceURL = document.forms["form1"]["ServiceURL"].value;

    html5sql.process(
         [
             "DELETE FROM employees"
         ],
         function(){
          alert("loading xml");
             loadXML(serviceURL);
         },
         function(error, statement){
             alert("Error: " + error.message + " when processing " + statement);
         }        
     );
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {

    html5sql.openDatabase("emp", "HTML5 Web SQL Database", 6*300000*300000);
    html5sql.process("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (empid , firstName, lastName, dob, title, department, officePhone, cellPhone, email, spousename, spousedob, marriageanniversary, picture, PRIMARY KEY (`empid`));")
    html5sql.process("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (ServiceURL);")

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      renderEmployeeList();
    });


    function renderEmployeeList(){

      html5sql.process( 
        [
          {
            "sql": "SELECT * FROM config",
            "success": function(tx, results) {
              var len=results.rows.length;
              if (len==null || len==""){//check if config(serviceURL) is empty. If it is, go to settings.
                alert("XML Path is missing. Please enter a path in the settings.");
                window.location = '#settings';
              }else{
                  html5sql.process(//if config exists, start rendering employees.
                    [
                      {
                        "sql": "SELECT * FROM employees",
                        "success": function(tx, results) {
                          alert("called output select");
                          var len=results.rows.length;
                          var i;
                          for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
                            $("#output").append('<a data-ajax="false" href="employeedetails.html?id=' + results.rows.item(i).empid + '"><li class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c"><div id="outputdiv" class="ui-content" style="cursor: pointer;">' + results.rows.item(i).firstName + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).lastName + '</div></li></a>');
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  );
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      );

    }
    }

    function loadXML(XMLurl){
      alert (XMLurl);
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: XMLurl,
          dataType: "xml",
          success: parseXml
        });  
    }

    function parseXml(xml)
    {

      $(xml).find("employee").each(function()
        {
          alert("each called");
          var $this = $(this),
          $empid = $this.attr("empid"),
          $firstName = $this.attr("firstName"),
          $lastName = $this.attr("lastName"),
          $dob = $this.attr("dob"),
          $title = $this.attr("title"),
          $department = $this.attr("department"),
          $officePhone = $this.attr("officePhone"),
          $cellPhone = $this.attr("cellPhone"),
          $email = $this.attr("email"),
          $spousename = $this.attr("spousename"),
          $spousedob = $this.attr("spousedob"),
          $marriageanniversary = $this.attr("marriageanniversary"),
          $picture = $this.attr("picture");

          alert("FName " + $firstName);

          html5sql.process(
            [
              {
                "sql": "INSERT INTO employees (empid , firstName, lastName, dob, title, department, officePhone, cellPhone, email, spousename, spousedob, marriageanniversary, picture) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                "data": [$empid, $firstName, $lastName, $dob, $title, $department, $officePhone, $cellPhone, $email, $spousename, $spousedob, $marriageanniversary, $picture],
              }
           ]
          );
        }
      )
    }




    /* Save Configuration */
    function saveconfig(){

      var serviceURL = document.forms["form1"]["ServiceURL"].value;

      html5sql.process(
        [
          {
            "sql": "DROP TABLE config"
          }
        ]
      );

      html5sql.process(
        [
          {
            "sql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config (ServiceURL)"
          }
        ]
      );

      html5sql.process(
        [
          {
            "sql": "INSERT INTO config (ServiceURL) VALUES (?)",
            "data": [serviceURL],
            "success": function(){
            alert("URL Saved.");
            loadXML(serviceURL);
            }
          }
        ]
      );

    }
```

I've used html5sql.js from html5sql.com

The function resync() doesn't give an error, infact, it calls loadXML with the correct ServiceURL.
But the changes in the remote xml are not reflected here. I'm stuck on this since days. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.